# How to combine the 'tar' command with 'find'

Tags: linux, centos, find, exec

The find command gives this output:

```
[root@localhost /]# find var/log/ -iname anaconda.*
var/log/anaconda.log
var/log/anaconda.xlog
var/log/anaconda.yum.log
var/log/anaconda.syslog
var/log/anaconda.program.log
var/log/anaconda.storage.log
```

After combining with tar it's showing this output:

```
[root@localhost /]# find var/log/ -iname anaconda.* -exec tar -cvf file.tar {} \;
var/log/anaconda.log
var/log/anaconda.xlog
var/log/anaconda.yum.log
var/log/anaconda.syslog
var/log/anaconda.program.log
var/log/anaconda.storage.log
```

But while listing tar file it's showing only a single file

```
[root@localhost /]# tar -tvf file.tar
-rw------- root/root    208454 2012-02-27 12:01 var/log/anaconda.storage.log
```

What I am doing wrong here?

With xargs I am getting this output:

> [root@localhost /]# find var/log/ -iname anaconda.* | xargs tar -cvf file1.tar

#### Second question

While typing **/** in front of var, means `find /var/log` why its giving this mesaage **tar: Removing leading `/' from member names**

```
[root@localhost /]# find /var/log/ -iname anaconda.* -exec tar -cvf file.tar {} \;
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/var/log/anaconda.log
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/var/log/anaconda.xlog
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/var/log/anaconda.yum.log
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/var/log/anaconda.syslog
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/var/log/anaconda.program.log
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/var/log/anaconda.storage.log
```

In a simple form what is the difference between in the following two?

`find var/log` and `find /var/log`

Comment: This is semi+off topic, but going forward with the `find` command, you should quote the search term. It works without sometimes but not always.

Comment: If you use `{} +` instead of `{} \;` it will group results of find into one argument

Answer (score 46, accepted):

***Note:** See [@Iain's answer](https://superuser.com/a/513319/48078) for a somewhat more efficient solution.*

Note that `find` will call the `-exec` action for *every single file* it finds.

If you run `tar -cvf file.tar {}` for every single file `find` outputs, this means you'll overwrite `file.tar` every time, which explains why you end up with one archive left that only contains `anaconda.storage.log` — it's the last file `find` outputs.

Now, you actually want to *append* the files to the archive instead of creating it each time (this is what the `-c` option does). So, use the following:

```
find var/log/ -iname "anaconda.*" -exec tar -rvf file.tar {} \;
```

The `-r` option appends to the archive instead of recreating it every time.

<sub>**Note:** Replace `-iname anaconda.*` with `-iname "anaconda.*"`. The asterisk is a wildcard and can be [expanded](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) by your shell before `find` even sees it. To prevent this expansion, wrap the argument in double quotes.</sub>

---

As for `tar` removing leading `/`: The archive should only contain *relative* file names. If you added files with a leading `/`, they would be stored as *absolute* file names, literally meaning `/var/…` on your computer, for example.

IIRC this is simply a precaution for `tar` implementations other than GNU, and it's safer this way because you won't overwrite your actual data in `/var/…` when you extract the archive if it contains relative filenames.

Comment: But note that if you tried `tar`ing to an actual tape archive this way, adding one file at at time, rewinding the tape, then rereading the whole thing each time to get to the end, the whole thing would be ridiculously slow.  Your solution is **only** suitable if you're writing the tar file to disk.

Comment: True, but I think we can safely disregard this situation ;)

Comment: @slhck * is a wildcard that should match all the possibility right? but here `find /var/log/ -iname anaconda*` giving nothing and `find /var/log/ -iname anaconda.*` giving the output, why?

Comment: When a wildcard is consumed, it won't be seen by `find` anymore. So if you have `anaconda*`, and in your current folder there's something named, for example, `anaconda5` (matching this wildcard), the wildcard will be expanded, and `find` will see `-iname anaconda5` instead of `-iname anaconda*`. Why the first doesn't work and the second does depends on what files are in your current directory. @max

Comment: You can use `{} +` instead of `{} \;` so it will group the results of find into one argument

Comment: A solution like this wouldn't (necessarily) be able to work for compressed tar files.  As @JasonS says, using `{} +` will allow the whole archive to be created in one go.

Comment: @mwfearnley it won't allow the whole archive to be created in one go if there are really many files. In this case the `+` will split the list into multiple invocations of `tar`, so that the command line fits length limit.

Answer (score 62):

You can use something like:

```
find var/log -iname 'anaconda.*' -print0 | tar -cvf somefile.tar --null -T -
```

The `-print0` and `-T` work together to allow filenames with spaces newlines, etc. The final `-` tells tar to read the input filenames from stdin.

Note that `-print0` must come at the end of your statement, per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209498/find-command-returns-different-results-when-print0-is-added/209526). Otherwise you will probably get more files than you expect.

Comment: You've omitted the `-name` option, causing your solution to `tar` the whole directory.  If that's what you want, you could do it more easily as `tar -cvf file.tar var/log` without using `find` at all.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton: You're right and it's easily fixed (which you could have done too). It doesn't affect what I was demonstrating which is that you can use `-` as the input file to tar so the output of find can be piped into it.

Comment: +1 Piping the list to `tar` is a good idea.  It's definitely the best solution if you expect the pathnames may have spaces.  I would even describe it as the best technically, since it's both reliable and efficient.  But it requires additional special knowledge of both `find` and `tar`.  I prefer command substitution pretty much only because it's a more general tool:  Learn how to use it once, then use it everywhere.  (But I concede, I'm on Windows with a shell where it always works.) Apologies if I seemed rude.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton: Do you not run the risk of `Argument List Too Long Error` because the command substitution expands onto the command line ?

Comment: You already got your +1.  Be happy. :)  Long command lines are always the bane of the process creation i/f on any OS.  I remember arguing with [Mark Lucovsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Lucovsky) at Microsoft in the early 90s that their 32K Unicode characters limit on NT was too small and having him complain I had no idea how many more bytes it would take to store lengths as longs rather than shorts everywhere in the kernel.  Sigh.    The more general case solutions when the arg list is too long are to do more in the shell (if possible; in mine it is) or use `xargs`.

Comment: if you use find's `-print0` option, you also need tar's `--null` option.

Comment: To expand on @mivk's comment, when tar reads what would be a file name containing a nul character, it will issue a warning and switch to treating the input as nul-terminated. However, this can break if any file names contain a newline character, as the nul character may be seen too late to make the switch. Given that the whole point of using nul terminators is to handle file names containing newline characters, the `--null` really needs to be specified.

Comment: And `--no-unquote` turns out to be needed as well: file names containing backslashes would otherwise be mishandled. (No, this isn't a hypothetical -- I'm really creating a tar archive from someone else's code, containing a filename with backslashes in the name, that's how I found out.)

Comment: @hvd then you should seek them out and give them a good kicking.

Comment: @user35787 You mean because they make you find a bug in your code?  ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
tar -cvf file.tar `find var/log/ -iname "anaconda.*"`
```

You were trying to use `find` to `-exec tar`.  But the way the `-exec` option works, it runs that command once for each matching file it finds, causing `tar` to overwrite the tar file it produces each time. That's why you only ended up with the last one.  Also, you need to put quotes around the pattern you specify to `find` so that the shell doesn't expand it before passing it to `find`.

Using command substitution with backticks (or using `$(...)` notation if you prefer), the entire list of names produced by `find` is pasted back onto the command line as arguments to `tar`, causing it to write them all at once.

Comment: This could end up bad if find outputs files with spaces in their name, newlines or globbing characters. This is bound to fail – piping stdout from `find` is rarely a good idea. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @slhck, piping stdout from find is in fact usually a good idea, as very clearly explained in the page you linked to in your comment :). It is in fact the recommended way to do things. You should just use some tricks (such as `read -r` of `-print0`) as I did in my answer.

Comment: @terdon Except that most people *don't* use the tricks and then wonder why their scripts fail (such as in this post).

Comment: @slhck This is why file and directory names in Unix and Linux have traditionally avoided spaces in names.  It's also why, on Windows, where names with spaces are common, I added an additional command substitution notation to my own [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/cshell.htm) using double backticks that treating the whole lines (possibly including spaces) as single words to be pasted back onto the command line.  Unfortunately, none of the Unix shells have that feature.

Comment: They might have traditionally avoided it, but with files being created in the user space through GUIs, you can't neglect files with spaces anymore and treat them as second class citizens (just because it's Unix). It's nice you included that in your shell, but it's for Windows, and Unix shells don't particularly *need* that feature if you simply use the right syntax and take proper precautions. Which is why I've posted my comment in the first place.

Comment: Does this business of using GUIs to create names with spaces happen a lot in `/var/log`?

Comment: No, but in other places it might very well happen. That's why it's a good idea to program defensively – better be safe than sorry. Also, visitors finding this question might not necessarily have the exact same problem and wonder why the command they've found here appeared to work for this very case but failed for them. I'll leave it up to you to fix the command, I just thought it was important mentioning it because many people run into this issue sooner or later.

Comment: All fine, but consider that Unix and Linux fundamentally don't handle spaces well period.  For example, consider the bashism of `for i in *; do a=$i; ls $a; done`, which fails for any name that contains a space.  The good news (as in the OP's case with `tar` as well) is that when you hit a name that does have a space and it fails, it would be pretty contrived for it to fail silently.  So you can usually safely try it the simple way, assuming no spaces, knowing that if it works, you're done.

Comment: Should also point out there's a difference between what you do interactively at the command line versus what you write in a script.  I generally try the simple solution first when I'm working interactively.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton: You stated `none of the Unix shells have that feature.` I do not completely agree: With `zsh` this ugly thing can handle white spaces in file names: `for i (${(f)"$(ls -1)"}) echo $i` as it splits on newlines; so things will break again, if the filename contains a newline (but IMHO that's an even more bad practice than with blanks). And, last but not least, your solution with double backticks is of course much cleaner -- I also like things simple in an interactive session `:)`

Comment: Anyone having issues with Linux spaces should check out the BASH $IFS  variable which allows you to define what characters serve as delimiters for BASH commands.

Answer (score 6):

### Question 1

Your command fails because `tar` is taking each of the files found and archiving them into `file.tar`. Each time it does so, it will overwrite the previously created `file.tar`.

If what you want is one archive with all the files, then simply run `tar` directly, there is no need for `find` (and yes, this works for files with spaces in their names):

```
tar -vcf file.tar /var/log/anaconda*
```

---

### Question 2

The two commands are completely different:

- find var/log will search a directory called `var/log` **which is a subdirectory of your current directory**, it is equivalent to `find ./var/log` (notice the `./`).
- find /var/log will search a directory called `/var/log` **which is a subdirectory of the root, `/`**.

The leading `/` message is from `tar`, not `find`. It means that it is removing the first `/` of your file names to make **absolute** paths into **relative**. This means that the file from `/var/log/anaconda.error` will be extracted to `./var/log/anaconda.error` when you untar the archive.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways `-exec` can work.  One way runs the command many times - once for each file; the other way runs the command once, including all the files as a list of parameters.

- `-exec tar -cvf file.tar {} ';'` runs the `tar` command for each file, overwriting the archive each time.
- `-exec tar -cvf file.tar {} '+'` runs the `tar` command once, creating an archive of all the files found.

Answer (score 1):

I think using -exec for each file can make the tar compression very slow, if you have a lot of files. I prefer use the command:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" | cpio -ov -H tar -F jpgs.tar
```

Comment: until it starts failing with `/bin/cpio: xxx: Cannot open: Too many open files`

Answer (score 0):

I can never remember find's exec syntax, so I cheat and do something simpler...

e.g. to grab all the *.sh files:

```
FOO=$(find . -name "*.sh") && tar cvf useful.tar $FOO
```

Apologies it's not elegant, but most of the time I don't need more effort than this. :D